# How to deal with partial relationship data returned while using AFIncrementalStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

Experimenting with AFIncrementalStore and it is pretty sweet.  However I've come across a scenario I am not entirely sure how to deal with.

I have a model that returns an id of a child relationship, but not the content itself. eg: 
GET /groups

```
{"id":3,"description":"My Group","category_id":2}
```

I can get all the categories with a regular GET /categories. But I do NOT have a call to GET /group/3/categories

So what I don't know is how I can initialize the child relationship of the group.category. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When using AFIS every object that you store have Resource Identifier. In most cases you want the id of the object to be its RI. So in that case category_id is the RI for your category object. So you can create category object only with its category_id. Then, when you get all categories, you will populate other fields of category objects. It is very simple because AFIS is smart enough.

There is another way also. Since you can get all the categories with a regular GET /categories then there should be field with group id for each category. So you can set the relationship from categories to their groups. It will automatically make the reverse relationship.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @nataliq's answer, this has to be in your AFRESTClient's implementation of `representationsForRelationshipsFromRepresentation:ofEntity:fromResponse:`. It should have the relationship name ("category") as the key, and another NSDictionary with the category's id as the value. If your Group object's Category relationship is named "category" and you standardize on having the other object's id property named with an _id suffix, you could do something like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)representationsForRelationshipsFromRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation
                                                           ofEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
                                                       fromResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
{
  NSMutableDictionary *mutableRelationshipRepresentations = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[entity.relationshipsByName count]];
  [entity.relationshipsByName enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id name, id relationship, BOOL *stop) {
    id value = [representation valueForKey:[(NSString *)name stringByAppendingString:@"_id"]];
    if (value && ![value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] &&  ![relationship isToMany]) {
      NSDictionary *valueDict = @{@"id" : value};
      [mutableRelationshipRepresentations setValue:valueDict forKey:name];
    }
  }];

  return mutableRelationshipRepresentations;
}
```